# How can I prevent the breaking out of a Fancybox IFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, fancybox

I have found that methods such as the below, can cause the breaking out of an IFrame.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(top.location != window.location) {
    window.location = 'www.IFrameDetected.com';
}
</script>
```

After some research I have determined that if I were using a regular IFrame in contrast to a fancybox IFrame, then sandbox options such as `sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-scripts"` with the exclusion of `allow-top-navigation` could be applied to circumvent the above mentioned break-out approach.

But I've not yet been able to find either a way to utilise this approach with a Fancybox Iframe, or found a method which specifically works with Fancybox IFrames. An example of my current fancybox is below.

```
$.fancybox.open({
    src: example.com,
    type: 'iframe',
    opts: {}
})
```

Comment: have you tried adding the sandbox attribute to the fancybox opt option?

Comment: Yes, the error _Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer_ is returned